# add icon to listbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, image, listbox, draw

please,

how do i draw image in listbox_DrawItem event by the left side

i already read throught [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774429/add-images-to-listbox-visual-basic), buts its not helping me

```
Dim targetsize As New Size(16, 16)
Dim img As Image = Nothing
img = My.Resources._error
e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, targetsize)
e.Graphics.DrawString(lsbLog.Items(e.Index).ToString(), _
                              e.Font, mybrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault)
```

this is my current code

EDIT

i added your code with some other code, and i get a garbled text

**this is part of the code in the DrawItem event**

```
'//Here it draws the border depeding on it's state (the listbox item)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, e.Bounds.X + 16, e.Bounds.Y, _
                                 e.Bounds.Width - 16, e.Bounds.Height)
        Using b As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(lsbLog.GetItemText(lsbLog.Items(e.Index)), e.Font, b, e.Bounds)
        End Using
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, New Rectangle(e.Bounds.Width - 15, e.Bounds.Y, 12, 12))
        '// Draw the current item text based on the current 
        '// Font and the custom brush settings.
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lsbLog.Items(e.Index).ToString(), e.Font, mybrush, _
                               New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X - 20, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height), _
                               StringFormat.GenericDefault)
```

This is the code in the MeasureItem event

```
 Private Sub lsbLog_MeasureItem(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventArgs) Handles lsbLog.MeasureItem
        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
        'We will get the size of the string which we are about to draw,
        'so that we could set the ItemHeight and ItemWidth property
        Dim size As SizeF = g.MeasureString(lsbLog.Items.Item(e.Index).ToString, Me.Font, _
        lsbLog.Width - (5 + SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth))
        e.ItemHeight = CInt(size.Height) + 5
        e.ItemWidth = CInt(size.Width) + 5
    End Sub
```

I get a garbeled text and image

[image: I get a garbled image]

Comment: Did you check out if this was any help? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/glistbox.aspx

Comment: @Simen people commented on that article as very poor and bug filled

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want the image to be left-aligned, why do you use `Width - 15` as the X coordinate? You should just use `e.Bounds.X` here. And why do you start the text *outside* the listbox (i.e. you set X to `e.Bounds.X - 20`)? Shouldn't that be `e.Bounds.X + 20`?

Comment: PS: Do you call DrawBackground at the beginning of your event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points come to my attention:

- Did you set the [DrawMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode.aspx) to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` or `DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable`, as [stated in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx)?
- You seem to be drawing the text directly over the image. Why do you use `e.Bounds` in DrawString instead of a rectangle that starts a little bit to the right? E.g. something like:

  ```
  Dim rect As New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 16, e.Bounds.Y, _
                            e.Bounds.Width - 16, e.Bounds.Height)
  ' use rect instead of e.Bounds in DrawString
  ```

BTW, you shouldn't forget to call `DrawBackground` and `DrawFocusRectange` as seen in the example [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx).

Comment: yes i set the drawmode to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable`. Can you give me the alternative to `e.bounds`

Comment: @Smith: I'd use OwnerDrawFixed, since you don't change the Height of the item. I've added an example on how to adapt the rectangle bounds for the string. BTW, as a hint for debugging: Does it draw the image correctly if you just comment out the DrawString statement?

Answer (score 0):

try this related post, you only need to edit a bit of code, based on the font size, I only needed it with 8.25pt font size, when the font size is larger the icon it's mess up, it doesn't lined up on the font height center

[Highlighting Listbox Item when Mouseover on Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705508/highlighting-listbox-item-when-mouseover-on-item)