# Highlighting Listbox Item when Mouseover on Item

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I manage to customize the normal list box with an image, change text and background color when item is selected in ownerdrawn, what I want to achieve now is to drawn a custom highlight color on the item when mouse is hover on the listbox item, is that possible or not..., I provided my sample code below on what I come so far..

```
If e.Index = -1 Then Exit Sub
        Dim listBox As ListBox = CType(sender, ListBox)
        e.DrawBackground()
        Dim isItemSelected As Boolean = ((e.State And DrawItemState.Selected) = DrawItemState.Selected)
        If e.Index >= 0 AndAlso e.Index < listBox.Items.Count Then
            Dim textSize As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(listBox.Items(e.Index).ToString(), listBox.Font)
            Dim itemImage As Image = My.Resources.FolderHorizontal
            'set background and text color
            Dim backgroundColorBrush As New SolidBrush(If((isItemSelected), Color.CornflowerBlue, Color.White))
            Dim itemTextColorBrush As Color = If((isItemSelected), Color.White, Color.Black)

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backgroundColorBrush, e.Bounds)
            'draw the item image
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(itemImage, e.Bounds.X + 2, _
                               e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - textSize.Height) / 2, _
                               itemImage.Width, itemImage.Height)
            'draw the item text
            Dim x, y As Single
            Dim h As Single = textSize.Height
            Dim rect As Rectangle = e.Bounds
            rect.X += listBox.ItemHeight
            rect.Width -= listBox.ItemHeight

            x = rect.X - 3
            y = rect.Y + (rect.Height - h) / 2

            Dim itemText As String = listBox.Items(e.Index).ToString()
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, itemText, e.Font, _
                                  New Rectangle(x, y, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height), _
                                  itemTextColorBrush, TextFormatFlags.Default)
            'clean up
            backgroundColorBrush.Dispose()

        End If
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IndexFromPoint to do something like that:

```
Dim mouseIndex As Integer = -1

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) _
                               Handles ListBox1.MouseMove
  Dim index As Integer = ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location)
  If index <> mouseIndex Then
    If mouseIndex > -1 Then
      Dim oldIndex As Integer = mouseIndex
      mouseIndex = -1
      If oldIndex <= ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
        ListBox1.Invalidate(ListBox1.GetItemRectangle(oldIndex))
      End If
    End If
    mouseIndex = index
    If mouseIndex > -1 Then
      ListBox1.Invalidate(ListBox1.GetItemRectangle(mouseIndex))
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Then in your drawing code:

```
If mouseIndex > -1 AndAlso mouseIndex = e.Index Then
  backgroundColorBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.DarkMagenta)
End If
```

Comment: thanks, It work's... with slight problem, how do I minimized the flickering, I think it redraw every time you move the mouse on the item, or there is another way do do it... but other than that, it works great

Comment: @mercenary The ListBox control is rather uncontrollably flicker happy, but I updated the post to reduce some of that.  Consider using a ListView control instead.

Comment: thanks, I'm thinking using listview, maybe on the next version of the tool, its a folder icon changer using listbox to accommodate multiple folder at once...

Answer (score 1):

I will show you how to do this.  All experts say its complicated and cannot be done with a listbox... I was able to do that in 5 minutes

the name of the listbox I created is `listPOSSIBILITIES`

1) create a variable which is global to your form

```
Dim HOVERTIME As Boolean = True
```

2) create `MouseEnter` event

```
Private Sub listPOSSIBILITIES_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As system.EventArgs) Handles listPOSSIBILITIES.MouseEnter

    HOVERTIME = True

End Sub
```

3) create `MouseLeave` event

```
Private Sub listPOSSIBILITIES_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles listPOSSIBILITIES.MouseLeave

    HOVERTIME = False

End Sub
```

4) create `MouseMove` event

```
Private Sub listPOSSIBILITIES_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles listPOSSIBILITIES.MouseMove

    Dim mypoint As Point
    mypoint = listPOSSIBILITIES.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
    Dim myindex As Integer = listPOSSIBILITIES.IndexFromPoint(mypoint)
    If myindex < 0 Then Exit Sub
    listPOSSIBILITIES.SelectedIndex = myindex

End Sub
```

5) create `MouseClick` event

```
Private Sub listPOSSIBILITIES_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles listPOSSIBILITIES.MouseClick

    HOVERTIME = False

End Sub
```

6) create `SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
Private Sub listPOSSIBILITIES_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles listPOSSIBILITIES.SelectedIndexChanged

    If HOVERTIME Then Exit Sub

    'put the rest of your code after this above If statement

End Sub
```

This works because the `MouseClick` event is triggered before the `SelectIndexChanged` event